# DQL: only last entry from a customer

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I am writing a query in DQL where I want to select the latest order from a customer. Currently I only managed to get all the orders and get them based on their date in a descending order. Which means I need to filter it to go per user as well as just pick their latest entry. However , my knowledge of DQL and queries in general isn't that high I am stuck. Any help on how to continue my query would be appreciated.

```
public function getLatestOrder($customer){
    // get the latest order from a customer

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $q1 = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->leftjoin("AppBundle:User", "u")
    ->where("u.id = :customer_user_id")
    ->setParameter('customer_user_id', $customer)
    ->orderBy('o.date', 'DESC' );

    $q1 = $q1->getQuery();
    $res1 = $q1->getResult();



    return $res1;       
}
```

Additional info: The order entity has a customer column which refers to the user info.

Comment: what about using ->setMaxResluts(1) ? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

Comment: thanks that worked, however I stille have multiple customers, which all have different orders.  Know from what I have been told to "filter" for that I still need to expand this query, problem is I don't really know how

Comment: Try ->join instead of ->leftJoin. LEFT JOIN return all Orders, no matter if there is user (matching the WHERE clausule) or not. (BTW, you are not using DQL, but the QueryBuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of join better you can use sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->createQueryBuilder('o')
->leftjoin("AppBundle:User", "u")
->leftjoin("AppBundle:Order", "laterOrder", 'WITH', 'laterOrder.date > o.date')
->where("u.id = :customer_user_id")
->andWhere("laterOrder is null")
```